# Bucar por Id o por campo en mongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo una colección llamada User intento buscar por el id o por el campo username
he intentado probar este código pero no me funciona

```
const username = req.params.id;
const user = await User.findOne({
  $or: [{ username }, { _id: username }],
});
```

este código solo buscar por el id pero no por el campo username

en que exactamente estoy fallando?

Comment: Entonces ¿`req.params.id` puede tener o un valor tipo `id` o un valor tipo  `username`? Parece que falta recibir `username`, por ejemplo `req.params.username` también, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas buscar por id es mejor usar de la siguiente manera:

```
const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
```

Si quieres buscar por un campo llamado username con el findOne es de la siguiente manera:

```
const name = req.params.username
const user = await User.findOne({ username: name });
```

Solamente si la variable se llama igual que el campo en tu db lo usas de la siguiente manera

```
const username = req.params.username
const user = await User.findOne({ username });
```

Ahora que si quieres buscarlo por ambas opciones hay dos manera

```
const username = req.params.username
const id = req.params.id
var user = await User.findById(id);
if (!user) user = await User.findOne({ username });
```

o similar a tu ejemplo

```
const username = req.params.username
const _id = req.params.id
var user = await User.findOne({ $or: [{ _id }, { username }] });
```

Yo lo acabo de probar y funciona bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si te sigue sin funcionarte debe de ser porque `username` no existe en ningún documento de tu db y por ende no encuentra nada, si te sale algún otro error por favor manda lo que te sale en consola.